# overriding repeated validation rules in yii

Tags: php, yii

plz i have some rules function that i dont want to change in its code (BaseModel from database)
and i make other rules function in the model , i want to change in it

the base one "dont ant to change"

```
public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('start_date, end_date, info, type_id', 'required'),

            array('start_date, end_date, type_id', 'length', 'max'=>10),

    }
```

and i want to change in other function in the model that inherit from the base model
here is its code

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = array(
                    array('start_date, end_date, type_id', 'length', 'max'=>16),
        );
        return array_merge($rules,parent::rules());

    }
```

the problem that it uses max value as 10 , not 16
i want it 16
even when i chenge last line to

```
    return array_merge(parent::rules(),$rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it might not work is because the rule for `'max'=>10` still exists in `rules()` irrespective of the order. Replacing the rule works for me.

```
public function rules(){
    $rules=parent::rules();
    $rules[1]=array('start_date, end_date, type_id', 'length', 'max'=>16);
    return $rules;
}
```

**Edit**

To replace the rule using `'start_date, end_date, type_id'` as the "key" you need a recursive [array search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
public function rules(){
    $rules=parent::rules();
    $index=0;//index of the rule
    outer: foreach($rules as $rule){
        if(array_search('start_date, end_date, type_id',$rule)!==false)
             break outer;
        $index++;
    }
    $rules[$index]=array('start_date, end_date, type_id', 'length', 'max'=>16);
    return $rules;
}
```

This checks for the existing rule and if it doesn't exist adds the rule as the last element of `$rules`. This won't work if someone edits the first element in the base class e.g to add a new property/field to the rule.

Comment: Thanks but i want the replace be based on the keys (start_date, end_date, type_id) not their id (1) as it may be changed after that in code , is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Just completed the same task, created a merging helper function:

```
public function mergeRules($parent, $rules)
{
    // creating curent rules map
    $rulesMap = [];
    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        $validator = $rule[1];
        $attributes = array_map('trim', explode(',', $rule[0]));
        if (!isset($rulesMap[$validator])) {
            $rulesMap[$validator] = [];
        }
        $rulesMap[$validator] = CMap::mergeArray($rulesMap[$validator], $attributes);
    }

    // checking for attributes in parent rules against created rule map
    if (!empty($rulesMap)) {
        foreach ($parent as $i => $rule) {
            $validator = $rule[1];
            if (empty($rulesMap[$validator])) {
                continue;
            }
            $attributes = array_map('trim', explode(',', $rule[0]));
            foreach ($attributes as $k => $attribute) {
                if (in_array($attribute, $rulesMap[$validator])) {
                    unset($attributes[$k]);
                }
            }
            // unset if we got inherited rule of same validator
            if (empty($attributes)) {
                unset($parent[$i]);
            } else {
                $parent[$i][0] = implode(', ', $attributes);
            }
        }
    }

    return array_merge($parent, $rules);
}
```

Then in rules() function you just call:

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.

    $rules = array(
        blablabla...
    );

    return $this->mergeRules(parent::rules(), $rules);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to give your rules a key.

From the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation)

```
Note: It is handy to give names to rules i.e.

public function rules()
{
    return [
        // ...
        'password' => [['password'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
    ];
}

You can use it in a child model:

public function rules()
{
    $rules = parent::rules();
    unset($rules['password']);
    return $rules;
}
```

In your case you could do this in your parent class:-

```
public function rules() {
        return array(
            'requiredArray' => array('start_date, end_date, info, type_id', 'required'),

            'maxLengthArray' => array('start_date, end_date, type_id', 'length', 'max'=>10),

    }
```

and in your child class:-

```
public function rules()
{
    $parent = parent::rules();
    $rules = array(
        'maxLengthArray' => array('start_date, end_date, type_id', 'length', 'max'=>16)
    );
    unset($parent['maxLengthArray']);
    
    return array_merge($parent,$rules);

}
```

Edit:

Keeping in mind that if you want to update only 'one' attribute within the 'maxLengthArray'... the others will have to be re-applied after 'unset' from parent (  obviously :)  ).

eg:-
Changing only type_id length... the child would look like:-

```
public function rules()
{
    $parent = parent::rules();
    $rules = array(
        'maxLengthArray' => array('start_date, end_date', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        'typeIdLength' => array('type_id', 'length', 'max'=>16),

    );
    unset($parent['maxLengthArray']);

    return array_merge($parent,$rules);

}
```